# Create an array from a value of an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I am very new when it comes to arrays. Before I am just hard coding all things through htm.

This is my question. Is it possible to create an array from the value of another array?

```
var pmmain =["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff", "ggg", "hhh", "iii", "jjj", "kkk", "lll", "mmm", "nnn", "ooo", "ppp"];
```

For example, I want to create an array out of "aaa" and so on. Is it possible? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Update:

I use the array as a menu. When I click one it does something like this.

```
a=4;

for (a=c; a<d; a++){

$("#pm-page-main") .append("<div class=\"main-box\" id=\"m-box"+a+"\"><div class=\"title-box\"><span class=\"reg-wht-bold\">"+pmmain[a]+"</span></div><BR><BR><img src=\"imgs\\"+pmmain[a]+".png\"></div>").hide().fadeIn(75);\}
```

"#highlights-enclosure" is sort of a stage where in the website highlights the clicked item.

Now that the menu is visible in the web page, let's say I want to click the 2nd item which would be "bbb". After clicking that,  another menu would appear and it should have in it it's children. When one of the children is clicked, the children would replace the "bbb" in the "#highlights-enclosure" stage.

Comment: Do you mean make an array called `aaa` in `pmmain`? Like `pmmain[0] = {"aaa": []}`, or maybe something more simple `pmmain = [["aaa"], "bbb", .. ]`? Or a new seperate array with just that value `"aaa"` in it?

Comment: I updated my question since it was lacking in info

Comment: I don't know what you want to do. But I'm almost certain you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Access the specific index and wrap it in brackets

```js
var pmmain =["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff", "ggg", "hhh", "iii", "jjj", "kkk", "lll", "mmm", "nnn", "ooo", "ppp"];

var newArray = [pmmain[0]];

console.log(newArray);
```

Avoid using `new Array` because if the passed in array element happens to be a number, it is considered as a parameter for [**arrayLength**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Syntax)

```js
var pmmain =[1, "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff", "ggg", "hhh", "iii", "jjj", "kkk", "lll", "mmm", "nnn", "ooo", "ppp"];

var newArray = new Array(pmmain[0]);

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: Don't use `new Array(pmmain[0])`. It won't do the right thing if `pmmain[0]` is a number.

Comment: @Barmar, wow! I did not know that. Is it because passing a number is a parameter for array length?

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. `new Array(5)` makes an array with 5 empty elements.

Comment: @Barmar, yes, it says so here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Syntax . Thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new array your can `push` values to it:

```
var first = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var second = [];
second.push(first[0]);
second.push(first[1]);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
var pmain = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff", "ggg", "hhh", "iii", "jjj", "kkk", "lll", "mmm", "nnn", "ooo", "ppp"];
var subArr = function(arr) {
var newArr = []
    for (var i in arr) {
       var each = [arr[i]];
         for (var j in each) {
           each = each[j].split("");
         }
      newArr.push(each);
    }
return newArr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to turn your current data structure into something like this:

```
[['aaa'], ['bbb']] // and so on
```

If that's the case, just `map` it:

```
var newArray = pmmain.map(function(item) {
  return [item];
});
```

---

If you want your data structure to look like this:

```
[['a','a','a'], ['b','b','b']] // etc.
```

Then do this:

```
var newArray = pmmain.map(function(item) {
  return [item.split('')];
});
```